# Do I need to debounce mousemove events in javascript?

Tags: javascript

[this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/#debouncing-mouse-events) talks about using requestanimationframe to debounce a mouse move event. Is that really necessary? I couldn't find any reliable information on how often mouse events actually run but from what I've observed they don't pile up while the thread is blocked so it should be self-regulating, right?

Comment: It's generally good practice, but whether it's strictly necessary is dependant on your use-case. But do take into account that not all users will be on dev-machines and this sort of change will have different effects based on the browser/hardware it's run on.

Comment: _"using requestanimationframe to debounce a mouse move event"_ - No, they don't "debounce" the `mousemove` event. They move the animation part into a `requestAnimationFrame()` callback. _"Again our tactic here is to **let the mouse events all proceed as often as the browser deems necessary**, and we have the draw calls happen independently of those events."_